# Git Bash for windows not working properly

Tags: node.js, bash, git, git-bash, git-for-windows

I am having a very annoying issue with git bash for windows.

When first lauching git bash, everything works fine, but after I type in `node -v` to check the nodejs version, nothing is returned and every subsequent text I type in is not displayed (although when pressing enter these commands' outputs get displayed).

In the image below I ran the commands in this order:
- node -v (no output)
- npm -v (no input displayed)
- git --version (no input displayed)

[Image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKiIO.png)

Everything started with a SIGFAULT error when running any node or npm command. After unninstalling git for windows and installing again, it is working like this.

But, when I use the bash as a attached terminal for vscode, I get these errors in every command I run:

[Attached terminal throwing Segmentation fault error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omzxw.png)

How can I solve it?

Comment: I have had no trouble using Git commands from within powershell (the VS code integrated terminal in Windows). Sounds configuration-specific to me.

Comment: @theMayer Git commands works well in powershell, but unix-commands does not, that's the problem

Comment: Oh, I see, I misread the question. I guess my thought there is to set up a Ubuntu VM and proceed accordingly :D

Comment: Do you have a function or alias named "node"? What does `type -a node` show?

Comment: @glennjackman It outputs: 
```sh
$ type -a node
node is aliased to `winpty node.exe'
node is /c/Program Files/nodejs/node
```

Comment: Did you know you have an alias for node? If you do `command node -v` do you get the effect that characters you type don't show up?